# Connect Application to Database theory

Tags: database

i have questions about how database works with application.

Is all applications required to connect to a server first inorder to connect to a database?
 For example: app  <- server <- database.

i have one more question: if i step up a database in my desktop and i wanted to use my java program, which is in my another pc, what is the easiest way to connect them? i did try mysql and db2, but they seems too complicated for me becuase i have no idea how to work them out.

one last question: if i have a db2 database in my linux, how do I get the host name or address, which is used for set up a connection in my java program that is not located in the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check IP Address of other system and you need to open firewall port for the database and then you can access to that database from any system in INTRANET.